# How to avoid counting duplicate data points

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like this

[image]

I need a summary of how many SITES per StandType had each SPECIES.

So essentially I need R to tell me how many A, C and G stands had ALFL. aNd so on.

I used the commands

```
xtab1 <- xtabs(~SPECIES +StandType, X2016RawData)

xtab1
```

This gives me a table that looks somewhat like this.

```
   A     C     G  
ALFL   3   1   0
AMGO   1   0   0 
BTWB   0   0   1
...
```

Here’s the trick. Since sampling was over multiple days there are duplicates for SPECIES and Sites.

In the sample above you can see that ALFL was seen twice in SITE A29 bringing the count for ALFL in StandType ‘A’ to 3 instead of 2.

I can’t go in and delete duplicates of species per stand type since the actual raw data file is over 22,000 data point across 400 sites.

How do I get R to count the same SPECIES once per SITE?

Comment: SMasson, any updates? If the answer works, please "accept" it. If not, you are unlikely to get any more help without feedback to say what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

How about ...

```
library(dplyr)
X2016RawData %>%
  select(-day) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(SPECIES, StandType) %>%
  count()
```